# How to use go the m th line and n th character of a file??

Tags: c++

If I want to insert or copy something from the the m th line and n th character in a file, what should I do? Is there a way better than using getline for m times and seekp? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way better than using getline for m times and seekp?

Not really! Lines aren't "special" at the operating system level; they're just parts of a text file separated by the newline character. The only way to get to line `m` of a text file is to read through all of the file until you've seen `m - 1` newlines. Your C++ library's `getline()` function is likely to have a pretty efficient implementation of that operation already, so you're probably best off just using that.

If your application needs to seek to specific lines of a large file many times during a single run, it may make sense to read in the whole file into a data structure at startup (e.g, an array of structures, each one representing a single line of text); once you've done this, seeking to a specific line is as easy as an array lookup. But if you only need to seek to a specific line once, that's not necessary.

A more memory-efficient approach for repeated seeks in larger files may be to record the file offset for each line number as you encounter it, so that you can easily return to a given line without starting over from the beginning. Again, though, this is only necessary if seeks will be repeated many times.